# Как полностью собрать проект

Tags: c++, windows, qt

У меня есть проект, написанный на *C++ QT*, программа, которая считает, сколько раз ты должен погладить кота. При сборке проекта в *exe* мне необходимо учитывать, под какую архитектуру я это собираю: *х32* или *х64*, и тут рождается ряд вопросов.

1. Если проект собрать под *х32*, чтобы его могли использовать пользователи с разными архитектурами, ничего криминального не произойдет?
2. Чтобы запустить проект на другой машине, необходимо вложить в папку с проектом все необходимые *dll*. Можно ли их каким-либо способом «вшить» в *exe* или обойти это? Так как пробовал уже перенести собранный проект, он весит около 60мб со всеми необходимыми библиотеками.

Comment: Укажите платформу для которой разрабатывается ПО

Comment: @Cerbo windows конечно же

Comment: Вопрос надо править, например тег добавить, а сюда не надо писать

Comment: Думаете, если вшить dll в проект, суммарный объём уменьшится? И кстати 60 мегабайт для десктопного проекта — это не много.

Comment: @VlaD по поводу суммарного объема, я спрашивал есть ли какой либо метод сократить список необходимых dll'ок

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: ну, если какую-то dll можно исключить, значит, она была не так уж и _необходима_?

Comment: @VladD допустим  msvcr1000.dll есть в стандартном пакете vc++ но многие не ставят этот пакет.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Если вы пользуетесь рантаймом, то эта dll необходима, и ссылки на неё лежат в объектном файле. (А это практически всегда.) Вы можете, конечно, надеяться, что эта же dll уже кем-то где-то сделана доступной при инсталляции другой программы, но если на какой-то системе это не так, ваше приложение просто не запустится. (С другой стороны, с рантаймом можно слинковаться статически, но суммарный размер от этого уменьшится по идее не так уж сильно: вряд ли линковщик сможет выкинуть много из рантайм-билиотеки.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте статическую линковку (описанную, например, в статье «[Qt — статическая линковка библиотеки под Windows](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137233/)»<sup>[[архив](http://web.archive.org/web/20151024140541/http://habrahabr.ru/post/137233)]</sup>), что, конечно же, скажется на конечном размере полученного бинарника.

В случае динамической линковки, ваше приложение в любом случае будет требовать динамические библиотеки Qt (.dll или .so).

Так же стоит помнить, что LGPL не позволяет статическую линковку. А в случае выбора GPL вы должны будете предоставить исходные коды своего ПО. Или приобретайте коммерческую лицензию Qt.

Comment: А можно по поводу лицензий подробней, ибо проект который я хочу собрать не имеет никакой экономической стоимости/важности.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: [gpl faq](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.ru.html). тут есть и про gpl, и про lgpl, и про статическую, и про динамическую компоновку.