# Не рисует картинку на другом компе

Tags: c++, qt

Отрисовываю картинку на форме

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.drawImage(0,0, img->scaled(this->size()));
```

На моём компе всё работает, переношу на другой (на нём нет Qt)- программа открывается, но картинки нету. Что не так? Какую-то DLL ещё не скопировал?

Статическую линковку не хочу использовать, например, по этой причине:

> Так же стоит помнить, что LGPL не позволяет статическую линковку. А в
>   случае выбора GPL вы должны будете предоставить исходные коды своего
>   ПО. Или приобретайте коммерческую лицензию Qt.

В случае с динамической линковкой, приложение не требует DLL, запускается, но не работает корректно...

Comment: Подобный вопрос уже задавался: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457842/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82/457844#457844

Comment: Раньше думал про статическую линковку... Сейчас хочу без неё... Нужно же просто найти либу... Не подскажите какую?

Comment: Могу предположить, что вам потребуются как минимум `QtCore` и `QtGui`. На моём Debian с Qt4 это соответственно `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4` и `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4`.

Comment: Плагины забыли скопировать. Посмотри директорию `plugins/imageformats`